# How to get event when user open system settings

Tags: android

I want to launch my activity wnen user open the device settings.Is there any way to find System setting is opening?

Answer (score 2):

yes by using Service Or AlarmManager on your app. can check if running app. is System setting?

Put this in your code:

```
try {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(thisActivity, AlarmReciever.class);
            Apps.sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(thisActivity, 2, intent1,
                    0);
            Apps.am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            long l = new Date().getTime();
            if (l < new Date().getTime()) {
                l += 100;
            }
            Apps.am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 100, sender);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Add this permission to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

and add this before :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MBRMOrion.AlarmReciever" />
```

create Class as:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) thisActivity
            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = am1.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
            .getPackageName(); //running app.
}
```

}